# Int pointer is not null and can be printed but can not be passed into a function without throwing a segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am assigning an int pointer a value pulled from `sscanf`.  I then want to pass it in to a method from a different file, `counters_add`. Although I can print out the value stored in the pointer and its address, as soon as I pass it to this method the program throws a seg fault.  From testing I know that the program does not even get inside this method before seg faulting.

This method takes parameters of `(counters_t *ctrs, const int key)`.  The `counters_t` object is a struct I have defined earlier in the file.

I don't prematurely free anything and have verified that neither `ctrs` nor `key` are `NULL`.  Why am I getting a segmentation fault?

```
int *key = malloc(sizeof(int));
//check if key is null here
sscanf(line, "%i", key);
printf("key: %i\n", *key); //this prints out the value
printf("key: %p\n", (void *)key); //this prints out the address
counters_add(ctrs, *key);//seg fault here, without even getting inside of method
```

Initialization of ctrs:

```
counters_t *ctrs = count_malloc(sizeof(counters_t));
if (ctrs == NULL) {
    return NULL; // error allocating set
} else {
    // initialize contents of set structure
    ctrs->head = NULL;
}
```

The rest of the code:

```
void
counters_add(counters_t *ctrs, const int key)
{
    if (key >= 0 && ctrs != NULL) {
        // allocate a new node to be added to the list if the key is not already      in the set
        if(counters_get(ctrs,key) == 0) {//if it doesnt already exist
            printf("after first if statement");
            counternode_t *new = counternode_new(&key);//create it
            printf("aftermaking new node");
            new->next = ctrs->head;//add it to the head of the list
            ctrs->head = new;
        } else {
            // increment the count
            for(counternode_t *curr = ctrs->head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next){
                if (*(curr->key) == key){
                    *(curr->count) = *(curr->count) + 1;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

int
counters_get(counters_t *ctrs, const int key)
{
    printf("in counters_get");
    if (ctrs == NULL) {
        return 0; // null counter
    } else if (ctrs->head == NULL) {
        return 0; // set is empty
    }//remove this in set
    else {
        for(counternode_t *curr = ctrs->head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next)
        {
            if (*(curr->key) == key)
                    return *(curr->count);
            printf("in loop");
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

static counternode_t  // not visible outside this file
*counternode_new(const int *key)
{
    counternode_t *node = count_malloc(sizeof(counternode_t));
    int *newkey = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    newkey = (int*) memcpy(newkey, key, (50  * sizeof(char)));
    //make sure key is not over 50 ints 
    if (node == NULL || newkey == NULL) {
        // error allocating memory for node or new key; return error
        return NULL;
    } else {
        node->key = newkey;
        *(node->count) = 1;
        node->next = NULL;
        return node;
    }
}
```

Here is the counters struct:

```
typedef struct counters {
    struct counternode *head;           // head of the list of items in set
} counters_t;
```

here is the countersnode:

```
typedef struct counternode {
    int *key;
    int *count; //pointer to counter for this node
    struct counternode *next;           // link to next node
} counternode_t;
```

Comment: The problem most probably lies with `ctrs`. How did you declare `ctrs`? Did you initialize it?

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Does `counters_add` have a prototype?

Comment: @JohnKugelman could you explain what this means?

Comment: @grass please post the code of the `counters_add` function.

Comment: "I declare ctrs in previous code and malloc memory for it. I also check to see if it is null." -- Don't tell us, **show us**. We should be able to copy-and-paste your code from the question and run it ourselves to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You are making to difficult to help you... The problem may be in `counters_get` or in `counternode_new`. Please show these functions as well. Btw. if you are using linux, compile it with `-g` and run a debugger of valgrind, this will you to narrow down where the segfalt happens. For us it is impossible to see where this could happen.

Comment: @grassss : I notice two same answers below and I was the first one to answer. if the answer helps you then please mark mine 'answered' . appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Don't just add multiple disconnected chunks of code. Start with the program that's showing the problem and narrow it down as much as you can so it still exhibits the same problem. You should be able to get it down to, say, 20 lines or so. Then post that complete program as a single block of code. As I said, we should be able to copy-and-paste your entire program and reproduce the problem ourselves. I for one am unwilling to copy-and-paste each of the 7 chunks of code currently in the question and figure out how to put them back together.

Comment: @grassss for you own sake, please use proper code indentation. You'll have a much easier time reading your code. And also for us it is a whole lot harder when the code is not properly formatted.

Comment: Have you considered that your problem has nothing to do with `key`?

Comment: @immibis I have.  I printed ctrs to make sure it wasn't null.  I put in a println right at the top of counters_add.  It never prints.  How can a seg fault occur when I'm not trying to access any memory? the function is not called before I get the seg fault.

Answer (score 2):

I see the problem in `counternode_new`:

```
static counternode_t  // not visible outside this file
*counternode_new(const int *key)
{
    counternode_t *node = count_malloc(sizeof(counternode_t));
    int *newkey = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    newkey = (int*) memcpy(newkey, key, (50  * sizeof(char)));
    ...
}
```

In `counters_add` you pass to `counternode_new` a pointer to the variable `d`.
Then in `counternode_new` you want to copy in `newkey` 50 bytes with `key` as
the source. But `key` is pointer to a **single** integer, so you are reading 49
bytes out of bound, this leads to undefined behaviour which may lead to a
segfault. Also you are only allocating space for a single `int` for `newkey`. Besides, you are copying 50 bytes, not 50 integers. I don't get where the 50 comes from.

So your `counternode_new` call in `counters_add` makes no sense, first you have to
allocate space for a `int[50]` array and pass that to `counternode_new`.

Comment: This seems true, and that was a big mistake to make, so I took out the 50 and just have space for a single int.  However, this doesn't explain why counters_add is not getting called at all.

Comment: @grassss I don't know, it should be, at least judging from the portion of the code you've posted. Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I notice that `newkey` is having only `sizeof(int)` allocated, whereas you seem to copying 50 bytes to newkey.

```
int *newkey = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
newkey = (int*) memcpy(newkey, key, (50  * sizeof(char)));
```